# 'pod install' installing the newest version of pod

Tags: ios, cocoapods

For example I have

pod 'Mixpanel', '~>2.9.2'

in my Podfile and no Podfile.lock. If I run 'pod install' it is installing the latest version which is 2.9.3 now. However if then I open newly created Podfile.lock, change version there, remove pods and then run 'pod install' again, it will download correct version.

According to 'pod install' specification:
For pods not listed in the Podfile.lock yet, it searches for the version that matches what is described in the Podfile (like in pod 'MyPod', '~>1.2')

Could you please tell, is it Cocoapods issue, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It will install latest in case there is no Podfile.lock.

Comment: If you want add new pod no need to run pod install , run pod update and donot delete your podfile.lock as well as your pods folder

Comment: @TimurBernikowich, then it seems that there is a mistake in specification https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/pod-install-vs-update.html see 'pod install' section, last sentence... Also why to mention pods versions in Podfile then?